# How important is the distance from the voltage regulator to the USB-C connection?

Tags: voltage, pcb, voltage-regulator

I have created a board using USB-C connectors for power and for UART. I use an STM32F103C8T6 processor and work currently on placing the parts down.

### How important is the distance of the regulator to the USB-C connection?

The board is powered with USB-C (5 V) from PC.

**Should I place the voltage regulator closer to the USB-C ports or to the microprocessor?**

Comment: Which voltage regulator it is? And how long is the distance from MCU to connector?

Comment: The regulator is the AMS1117-3.3. From the MCU the Distance is around 35mm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the regulator is AMS1117 and there is 35mm between USB connector and MCU, it makes no practical difference if you put the regulator more closer to connector or MCU.